# <p and <h2 align=center not working

Tags: html, css, alignment

My code on kodle.co.uk/HTML is not working. The

and  tags are not working. Image below.

Thanks,
Harry
[image: code]

Comment: Well, first of all you're not using CSS. Secondly, it's "center", not "centre".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS like so:

```
<style>
p, h2{
     text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Or inline CSS:

```
<p style="text-align:center;"> </p>
<h2 style="text-align:center;"> </h2>
```